# How to add elements from several arrays to a new static array without ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

For a school assignment, I have successfully created a program which stores recipes (name, ingredients, instructions). I now need to add a shopping list feature which will take the ingredients from the recipes I've added and store them in a new static string array.

I have been required to create the ingredients string array with a size of 20 and the shoppingList as a static string array with a size of 40:

```
private String[] ingredients = new String[20];
private static String[] shoppingList = new String[40];
```

I initialized all elements of both arrays to an empty string.

I've also hard coded two recipes in my test program like this:

```
rcp1.setIngredients(0, "Butter");
rcp1.setIngredients(1, "Garlic");
rcp1.setIngredients(2, "Parsley");
rcp1.setIngredients(3, "Bread");
rcp1.setIngredients(4, "Cheese");

rcp2.setIngredients(0, "Biscuits");
rcp2.setIngredients(1, "Pepperoni");
rcp2.setIngredients(2, "Pizza sauce");
```

This is where I get stumped:

```
public void setIngredients(int loc, String ingredient) {
    ingredients[loc] = ingredient;

        for (int i=0; i<shoppingList.length; i++){
            if (shoppingList[loc] == "") {
            shoppingList = ingredients;
            } 
        }      
}
```

Because the ingredients of rcp1 and rcp2 both use the ingredients locations [0, 1, 2], trying to add the ingredient to the static shoppingList using [loc] results in it overwriting those locations of the first recipe.

I've created the for loop so it could properly display the first recipe's ingredients; however, I'm not sure how to then proceed to find the location of the next empty string in order to list the ingredients of the second recipe. I was thinking that I would have to use an else if statement and then figure out a way to find where the next empty string is so I can begin to add the next recipe's ingredients from that point..?

Is there any other, possibly simpler, way that I could take the ingredients from rcp2 and place them after rcp1's ingredients in shoppingList?

I think I've been over-analyzing this problem and I haven't been able to find a solution yet, so I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose of your `setIngredients()` function? The for loop that's inside is useless - you don't use the iteration variable `i` inside the body.

Comment: What you're saying sounds to me that you just need to concatenate the ingredients of both recipes to another array `shoppingList`, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a lot of artificial constraints, which is expected since this is a course assignment. Your main problem is that - apparently - you don't know how many ingredients are in each recipe, or in the shopping list. Normally, the array would be the right size for the contents so you would have the number of items in `arr.length`. Otherwise one would use one of the classes in the collections framework, like ArrayList.

However, you are using fixed-size buffers, which means that you need to track the *current size* of your list in addition to the *capacity*, which is what `arr.length` gives you. There are two ways you can do it:

- Explicitly, by having an `int` variable that is conceptually associated with the array to mean "first unused element". When you add new elements, you would start at that index, and increment that variable for every new ingredient added to the list. This is what ArrayList does.
- Implicitly, by having some kind of "marker" String that would mean "unused". This can be a proper String instance, or simply `null`. This is basically what C does with the `'\0'` string terminator.

Each option has different trade-offs and requires a different implementation, which I'm not adding here since you need do think about it as part of your course! Do not hesitate to ask more if you're stuck again, though.